# show permutation graph is a perfect graph

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

I need to prove that permutation graph is a perfect graph.
I've shown that for any $i<j$, $\{i,j\}$ connected iff $f(i)>f(j)$.
In addition, I know that the complement of a permutation graph is a permutation graph.
Then, it's enough to prove it has no odd cycles $c(n)$ for $n>1$.
I tried to prove by contradiction. Suppose $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n+1}$ are the vertices of the cycle.
Now, it will be nice to assume that $x_1<x_2<x_3<...<x_{2n+1}$
as then we're done, but it's wrong, because we can have the permutation:
$f:=(3,4,1,2)$ and we get $c(4)$ and if we assumed $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$ we got a contradiction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to explain what a permutation graph is...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph from wikipedia

Comment: Permutation graphs are comparability graphs, comparability graphs are perfect. Which part do you find hard to prove?

Comment: Is that true to claim that permutation graph has no cycles c(n) for any n>4...(even or odd)

Comment: No, that is not true, consider the permutation that maps $1,2,3,4,5,6$ to $6,5,4,3,2,1$. But it is also irrelevant: for perfection you only need to care about *induced* *odd* cycles and anti-cycles.

Comment: thank you, I meant induced cycles...do you have an example or it's right now? (for even or odd cycles >4)